# How can rotate animation 90 degree every time?

Tags: android

I want to animate a 90 degree rotation when a click is received.
The first click is working properly.
But from the second click, it doesn't work:
It rotates 180 degrees from the second click.

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 45, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(0);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setDuration(200);

btnPlus.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `toDegrees` angle be `90` instead of `45`?

Comment: modify start and end degree before you click or you will rotate from 0 to 45 all the time

Comment: Thanks!! I knew that degree continues to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView iv;
    private Button btn;
    float startDegress =-90;
    float endDegress = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startDegress+=90;
                endDegress+=90;
                RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(startDegress, endDegress, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

                anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                anim.setRepeatCount(0);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                anim.setDuration(200);

                iv.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

another way
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private ImageView iv;
private Button btn;
int i = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(i>3){
                i=i%3;
            }
            ObjectAnimator  oa2= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "rotation", i*90,(i+1)*90);
            oa2.setDuration(1000);
            oa2.start();
            i++;
        }
    });
}
```

}